# C# Display fraction line

Tags: c#, .net

I need to draw image that will display two numbers using fraction line and I was wondering do you maybe know some easy way to do it instead of calculating where to put line.

What I mean is is there any way to format string to show numbers like that and put the string on image.

So instead of displaying something like this 4/5 I would like to display it in way that 4 is top number, beneath it there is straight line and then number 5.

Comment: Where do you need to do this? Winforms, WPF, Console, ASP.NET, etc?

Comment: I need to draw image with number displaying like that so I can go with calculating and drawing straight line but I was wondering if there is some way to display number like that in string and then just put the string on image.

Comment: How are you drawing the image?